# R crosstalk filter_select: cannot unselect already selected value

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, crosstalk

I am trying to use `crosstalk` to filter a `plotly` chart. I use `crosstalk`'s `filter_select` to (un)filter a `plotly` chart. When using the reprex below trying to select a flower (e.g. setosa), all works fine. But when I unselect the flower, the values are not 'returned' to the `plotly` chart. Selecting '(All)' does not seem to be working either. The values reappear only when deselecting from flower filter AND ticking TRUE in the helper_select_all.

```
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)

df <- iris
df$helper_select_all <- T

shared_data <- SharedData$new(df)

filter <- bscols(
  list(
    filter_select("flower", "Select a flower", shared_data, ~Species),
    filter_checkbox(
      "helper_select_all",
      label = "Reset filtering as deselecting from 'Select a flower' is not working",
      shared_data, ~helper_select_all)
  )
)


p <- plot_ly(shared_data, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width) %>% 
  add_markers()


bscols(filter, p)
```

This picture demonstrates the issue as no filtering value is selected, but a part of the data is missing.
[image]

This picture shows what it looks like when all datapoints are present.
[image]

"(All)" does not seem to be working either.
[image]

Comment: If you want to remove the "(All)" selection, install version 1.1.1 of `crosstalk`. Your graph will default to plotting all points, but you can then switch between selections appropriately.

Comment: @DanielL I tried to install a newer version of crosstalk, but it does not seem to be working. When I select  "(All)", not all points are actually selected.

Comment: The newer version of `crosstalk` (1.2.0) also has (All) option, seems that specifically 1.1.1 doesn't.

Comment: @tosdanielle I don’t have any problem with having “(All)” present as part of the filter. My problem is that the selecting “(All)” does NOT select all data.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny I loaded version 1.2.0 of `crosstalk` and can confirm the "(All)" selection does not select anything. I'd suggest installing version 1.1.1 of `crosstalk` and setting the multiple argument to TRUE, `filter_select("flower", "Select a flower", shared_data, ~Species, multiple = T)`. To install version 1.1.1, `remotes::install_version("crosstalk", version = "1.1.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` then load. It is not a perfect solution but probably the best option.

Comment: For those interested [here](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk/issues/125) you can find the related GitHub issue.